# Выравнивание текста в QTextEdit по правому краю

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtextedit

Уже довольно долго ломаю голову над правильным выравниванием текста в `QTextEdit`. На данный момент мое поле вывода выглядит так:

[image: Поле вывода]

Как сделать так, чтобы текст выравнивался по правому краю? 
Пробовал прописывать `setTextAlign()`, но это не помогает.

Вот нерабочий код:

```py
 layout = QGridLayout(self)
 self.field = QTextEdit()
 self.field.setReadOnly(True)
 self.field.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
 self.field.setStyleSheet('font-size: 35px')
 layout.addWidget(self.field, 0, 0, 1, 5)
```

**UPD:** Ошибка найдена. Все дело в том, что после этого для `self.field` я использую метод `setText()`, при этом выравнивание автоматически ставится по левому краю. 
Как решение - каждый раз после использования `setText()` снова прописывать `self.field.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что у вас не так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.field = QTextEdit("Hello <br>World")
        self.field.setReadOnly(True)
        self.field.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.field.setStyleSheet('font-size: 35px')

        button = QPushButton('Button')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.field, 0, 0, 1, 5)
        layout.addWidget(button, 1, 0)

    def onButton(self):
        self.field.setText("12345 <br> 6789")
        self.field.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app = QApplication([])
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только что понял ошибку, в вопросе не указал.
В дальнейшем я пользуюсь методом `.setText()`, видимо он все и ломает. Можно как-то заменить его или придется каждый раз ставить выравнивание?

Comment: @SIA придется добавить

Comment: в любом случае спасибо)